# Prevent crashes in a Backbone.js app with unexpected data in model

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, node.js, backbone.js

I built a huge backbone.js app which works this way :

[image]

As you can see, there is a **Data** backbone.js model, which values are accessed by getters in **Getters.js** and the values are used in **Underscore templates** to define some inline styling. The contents in the page are present in another Backbone model, called **Contents**.

The page is basically built by three elements : **a menu, a content, and a bottom bar**. each one of these elements have their own templates **but they are all included in the same template**. This means that View.js, in it's render() function, fills the page body by running the main template, which displays the menu, and which includes the content and bottom bar templates.

This worked very well until I deployed that in production; the Data backbone model is built from a JSON file which comes from another app, and what I didn't know is that this **JSON can sometimes be different than what I expected with my getters.** This means that some values may be missing, some which are expected as a string could be an object containing that string and so on.

This is a huge problem because the getters often produce "cannot read value color of undefined". If all they did was returning values from the backbone model, it would be OK because they would simply return **undefined** values or other values than the ones expected. But because they also **do some logic** (as shown by getBottomBarColor in my example), they get undefined or unexpected typed values and try to work with it, which makes them crash.

The templates are nested, and pre-compiled by browserify.js into JS functions. This means that if a getter crashes at some point, the whole function (which means the whole template) crashes, **resulting in a blank page**.

Code is already in production and it is too late to change the way this whole app is built. I have been thinking of some way to handle malformed Data problems. **My getters.Js file is 3000 lines big** so it would be too long to make some manual edit to put try catches everywhere in it, so I thought about putting something like this at the end of getters.js :

```
_.each(getters, function(getterFunction, getterName){
    getters[getterName] = function(){
        try{
            return getterFunction.apply(this, arguments);
        } catch(e){
            sendErrorToDevByAjax(e, getterName);
            return "";  
        }
    }
});
```

This would avoid crashes in the getters, but this would be slow(try catch), and this is not unbreakable as I return an empty string in case of a crash, which is OK if the template expected a string there, but if the template expected a bool or an object, it is going to crash anyway (so I would have to put try catches in template calls too, this would become way too slow in my opinion)

If someone has an idea of something else which i could do to prevent crashes, or a way of doing what I plan to do **better**, i will gladly take it.

Comment: do the functions which expect objects check if the desired property exists before accessing it?

Comment: For the function params, you can do `getterFunction.apply(null, arguments)` instead of declaring each one.

Comment: nice, I was looking into using the arguments obj, but didn't think about using apply with it.
No, functions expecting objets and trying to accessing its property dont check every time if the object is defined. I don't know what I could return to them to avoid crashes. Also, I am wondering if the impact of try catches won't be too heavy on mobile devices for example

Comment: How about implementing a proxy on your server, which fetches the json from 3rd party, and mocks any missing data in the expected format?

Comment: I edited it with your apply -
I could even format the json on the client side before doing anything else with it, but this json is really big, with a lot of different configurations, and it would be very long to write a formatting class for it, and as I said this code is sadly already used by the app so I am looking at fast solutions

Comment: I tried to implement that solution, I had scope problems so I replaced null with this in apply(). works well on desktop, i am going to test on slower devices